What are the "Arnold invariants" of plane curves?
Paul Seidel said in 2023 that "Arnold invariants are hard to learn about from either Google or GPT".(reference) In fact, there is not even a Wikipedia article about them! So I thought: "Maybe Math Stack Exchange can help more!" And why is that I do want to know about them? Just out of curiosity, because as Wikipedia says "According to Marcel Berger, Arnold revolutionized plane curves theory."
So, I ask: What are the "Arnold invariants" of plane curves?
P.S. My background in differential geometry is the undergraduate book by Andrew Pressley (2001), Elementary differential geometry.

Might be useful: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101002966?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-7&rr=8c8d88426fcdbad9

Another useful text: https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.00871

Arnold invariants are a family of mathematical quantities associated with curves, particularly in the context of knot theory and singularity theory. These invariants are used to classify and distinguish different curves based on their topological and geometric properties.

$J^+$-invariant is one of the most well-known Arnold invariants. It is a numerical value associated with a plane curve that measures the curve's "strangeness" or complexity. The $\mathbf {J^+}$-invariant is defined for immersed curves, which are curves without self-intersections. Another significant Arnold invariant, the $\mathbf {St}$-invariant, is related to the number of double points a curve has. It provides a measure of the curve's complexity in terms of its self-intersections.
Applications
Arnold invariants have applications in various fields, They can be used to distinguish different knots and links.
They help in studying the local behavior of singularities of maps.
They have applications in areas such as quantum field theory and statistical mechanics.
A Visual Example is here.
Consider two simple closed curves: a circle and a figure-eight. These curves have different topological properties. The circle has no self-intersections, while the figure-eight has one. The Arnold invariants of these curves would reflect these differences, distinguishing them based on their topological complexity.

